# How to only add lines using patch?

Tags: linux, command-line, diff, patch

I'd like to be able to use diff & patch in order to write new lines to a file. To clarify what I mean a bit:

Original file: `test1.repo`

> exclude=mongo*
>
> exclude=sqlite*
>
> exclude=postgresql*

New file: `test2.repo`

> exclude=mongo*
>
> exclude=postgresql*
>
> exclude=mysql*

So I run the command `diff -u test1.repo test2.repo > repo.patch` to find the differences, simple enough. Looking at the `repo.patch` file I just made, I see the output:

> exclude=mongo*
>
> -exclude=sqlite*
>
> exclude=postgresql*
>
> +exclude=mysql*

If I use the patch as is though, it will write over with what is effectively just the data I have in `test2.repo`. Is there a way to get patch to **only** write new lines (*anything starting with a +*)? I'd like to add lines to the original repository, but not destroy any customization they've already done to their file.

Comment: What about replacing these remove lines in the patch by running e.g. the sed script `sed 's/^-\([^-]\{2\}\)/ \1/'` on it?

Comment: Might work for this example but would fail for lines that actually start with `--` for some reason. Personally I just manually edit the patch to sort out conflicts.

Comment: You can use `cat <(head -n 1 repo.patch) <(grep -ve '^-' repo.patch)  | patch` to address the problem pointed at by @frostschutz. But with these modified patch files I get the error `patch: **** malformed patch at line 9:` (thats the EOF), because you also need to modify the `@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@` lines?!

Comment: You're right @mpy, by directly modifying the patch file like this I would need to update the location reference line too. It's easy to do by hand, but I need the whole process to be automated, hence the original question.

Comment: For the given input, `sort -u test1.repo test2.repo` could also work.